# Return nested class objects within my Model back to my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC c# web app.

I have a Model which is populated in my controller and is rendered to my View.

This Model has nest class List object to the 2nd level.

This Model allows for checkboxes etc to be rendered in my View which i use Razor to do.

Ultimatley, I wish the User to be able to check/uncheck etc the checkbox values.

But for now, proof of concpet I just want to call a method on my controller to return the default values.

One of the ways i saw to persist the Model data was to use Hidden Fields.

This has worked to the 1st level of nested class objects but not the next layer.

To explain better these are my Models I am using in this View:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("preferences")]
public class PreferencesModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Message to display to user on UI
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string MessageToUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores Preferences
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("section")]
    public IList<SectionModel> SectionModel { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("section")]
public class SectionModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of Section (for Grouping Purposes)
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// List of Preferences for this section
    /// </summary>
      [XmlElement("preference")]
    public List<PreferenceModel> PreferenceModel { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("preference")]
public class PreferenceModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of HTML Control ie radio button, textbox
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of Preference
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
     /// <summary>
     /// 
     /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("options")]
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("options")]
public class Option
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("OptionName")]
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("OptionValue")]
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my View relating to the Model bit:

```
@for (int i = 0; i != Model.SectionModel.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].Name, "Name")
    <div style="clear: left; padding-left: 20px;">
        <h1>@Html.Label(Model.SectionModel[i].Name)</h1>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        @for (int j = 0; j != Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel.Count; j++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Type, "type")
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name, "Name")
    

            switch (Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Type)
            {
                case "check":
                    <p>@Html.Label(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)</p>
                    for (var r = 0; r != Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options.Count(); r++)
                    {
                        if (Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value == Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionValue)
                        {
                            @Html.CheckBox(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionName,true)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             @Html.CheckBox(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionName, false)
                        }
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value, Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionName)
                    }
                    break;
                case "radio":
                    <b>@Html.Label(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)</b>
                        for (var r = 0; r != Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options.Count(); r++)
                        {
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options, "option")
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionValue,"OptionValue")
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionName, "OptionName")

                            if (Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value == Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionValue)
                            {
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value, Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionValue, new
                                {
                                    @checked = true
                                })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value, Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionValue)
                            }
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value, Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options[r].OptionName)
                        }
                    break;
                case "text":
                    <b>@Html.Label(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)</b>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value)
                    break;
                case "textarea":
                   <b> @Html.Label(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)</b>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value)
                    break;
                case "combo":
                   <b>@Html.Label(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)</b>
                    var options = Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options;
                    var items = new SelectList(options, "OptionValue", "OptionName");
                    @Html.DropDownList("Options",items,Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Value)
                    @Html.Hidden("Options",Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options)
                   break;
                default:
                    <div>test dud</div>        
                    break;
            }
             <div class="clear"></div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

setting a break point then the user submits the View/Model back I get this:

[image]

As you can see the Option values (just test for the Radio buttons at this stage) are empty.

what should I do or is there a 'cleaner' way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you select any of the radio buttons?

Comment: @SamGhatak Hi, no not for this test as the User may not ,make any changes

Comment: Ok, thats certainly a valid case. But I was asking if you are getting the value even after selection or it still stays the same?

Comment: @SamGhatak Ok, I see you point - sorry - will try that now

Comment: @SamGhatak OK - just tried that and it made no difference - but good thinking

Comment: When binding lists, make sure that element 0 (of any array of inputs) contains a value. In this particular case, capture the request sent to your controller action (with Fiddler or otherwise) and see if element 0 is submitted for `Options` array of inputs.

Comment: @jeyoung they do contain values. that is not the issue. thanks

Comment: Not sure whats going on, another try- can you post the html snippet generated for the radio button? To verify if there is any model-binding issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the following from the view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Options, "option")
```

`Options` is a complex property (typeof `List<Option>`) and the html your generating is

```
<input type="hidden" value="System.Collections.Generic.List[yourAssembly.Option]" length="6" ... />
```

The `value` attribute is because its the `.ToString()` value of the property, and it cannot be bound to your collection so binding fails. Note the `length="6"` is because the 2nd parameter of `HiddenFor()` adds html attributes and there are 6 characters in "options"